# Run a shell script in a new cygwin window

Tags: cygwin

How can I run a shell script in a new cygwin window? The following just opens up the windows type of cmd window which is difficult to resize.

cygstart /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/bash ~/runmyapp.sh

Comment: I tend to use screen inside mintty.

Comment: The terminal program is called `mintty`. So try something like `mintty ~/runfxtransact.sh &`

Comment: how do I keep it open? It closes after the script runs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to keep the window open after the script exits, you have to do something to make the shell that is executing the script not exit.

Here's an example that should work.

```
mintty bash -c "~/runfxtransact.sh; read -p \"Press enter to close this window.\"" &
```

Comment: why is it that Ctrl-C doesn't kill the script when running in a new window?

Comment: Not knowing anything about the script, it's virtually impossible for me to even guess. The only suggestion I have is to make sure the correct window has the keyboard focus.